# How to override protected _prepareLayout function in block in Magento 2?

Tags: blocks, magento-2.2.5, override-block

I wanted to make changes in **_prepareLayout()** in block.
Code is as follow:

> Block: **Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View**

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs::class);

    $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    if ($category) {
        $title = $category->getMetaTitle();
        if ($title) {
            $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title);
        }
        $description = $category->getMetaDescription();
        if ($description) {
            $this->pageConfig->setDescription($description);
        }
        $keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords();
        if ($keywords) {
            $this->pageConfig->setKeywords($keywords);
        }
        if ($this->_categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
            $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
                $category->getUrl(),
                'canonical',
                ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
            );
        }

        $pageMainTitle = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
        if ($pageMainTitle) {
            $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName());
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

As per above code, I want to make change in below data:

```
if ($this->_categoryHelper->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
      $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
          $category->getUrl(),
          'canonical',
          ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
      );
}
```

Help me to change the parameter passed to **addRemotePageAsset()** by overriding block.

Answer (score 1):

you can not override protected methods in Magento 2, only the public method can be overridden using plugin or preference. there is no way to override protected and private method in Magento 2.

Comment: So how can i add custom code to _prepareLayout() as i have mentioned in my code?

Comment: using preference we can rewrite the whole class, I don't know about what you've mentioned. Give me any document where it shows it cannot possible to override a protected function

Comment: @Parthavi have a look at it https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126260/why-protected-methods-cant-be-intercepted

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran u mean that we can use preference for overwriting protected method

Comment: Yes we can use it.

Comment: you can rewrite protected method, but not a private one I will post an example :p

Answer (score 1):

In your custom module (lets assume the module is in app/code/Extend/Simple)

etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" type="Extend\Simple\Block\CategoryView" />
</config>
```

create class "CategoryView" under Extend\Simple\Block

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Extend\Simple\Block;

class CategoryView extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
       //Your function goes here
    }
}
```

run setup upgrade

or

cache flush & setup di compile

Comment: It's very important to remove _parent::_prepareLayout();_ from your __prepareLayout()_ method.

Comment: @WaPoNe removing means you are throwing off the old functionality, it's not always a good idea to discard if fully, it depends on the business needs.